# AS3 object notation for variable

Tags: actionscript-3

I have some variables in the format:

```
var like6Y:Number = 50;
```

Later I am dynamically setting some:

```
num=6;
```

Then I am trying to use that num to get the variable like6Y:

```
 like+6+Y
```

I know that is totally wrong but I seem to remember you could use some kind of object notation to accomplish this:

```
["like"+num+"Y"]
```

Or something along those lines. But I can't remember how to do it.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be done - just access `this["like"+num+"Y"]`. Assuming `like6num` is a property of the current object, otherwise just change `this` to the object's name.

Answer (score 2):

Even though something like `this["like" + num + "Y"]` would work for global variables, the datatypes `Array` and `Vector` *(use Vector if you know all values will be of the same type and that every index of it's length will be assigned a value)* are *built* for the task of accessing a value by an integer reference. They also provide the added benefit of giving you greater control of the scope in which the variables are placed.

For instance:

```
var likeY:Array = [-10, 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50];
var num:int = 6;
trace(likeY[num]); //prints 50
```

Answer (score 1):

in Javascript you can use `window["like"+num+"Y"]` or `eval("like"+num+"Y")`... but there is no alternative in AS3.

Also `this["like"+num+"Y"]` work if you are trying to access a public *property of the current class.

But there are some third party libs which brings the eval method to AS3. I never used it, but you can try,
[Eval in AS3: Tips for Executing Dynamic Actionscript][1]
http://danielmclaren.com/node/113

Comment: The bracket syntax is the way to go, I'd try to stay away from eval() in both JavaScript and ActionScript.

Comment: I think the alternative might involve reflection, which is most likely overkill for what the OP wants to do.